# self.view setNeedsDisplay and self.view setNeedsLayout are not working

Tags: ios, xcode

I have a main view controller showing on the screen and a class (delegate) running in the background getting positions.   When I get the result I call the delegate method in the view controller to update the label on the screen.  I tried several ways but still no update to the screen.

Here is the method:

```
-(void) updateDisplay
{

    NSLog(@"%@",myPosition.currentArea);
    _area.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"area = %@",myPosition.currentShopArea];


    //[self.view performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(setNeedsDisplay) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
    [self.view setNeedsDisplay];
    //[self.view setNeedsLayout];
}
```

I check the console, it displays the correct area but on the screen still showing null. I tried all three ways (commented out above) but none of those update the screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try 2 things:

1. calling `updateDisplay` on the main thread:

   ```
   [delegate performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(updateDisplay) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
   ```

   in the end, it is accessing `UIKit`, so better doing it right;
2. if that does not help, try with:

   ```
   [_area setNeedsDisplay];
   ```

   In this case also, if would be advisable to call the method on the main thread.