# xcode viewcontroller hiding fields not working

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad

I have a view controller with labels, textfields, activity indicator and a button control all tied with IBOutlets and accessible from within my code.

When the user presses the button, I hide a few of the fields, and put up the activity indicator. I then make a synchronous URL call to get some JSON data.

The view controller is not updated to reflect the activity indicator and hidden fields until AFTER the synchronous request returns. I need this to happen before the request returns so the users sees that something is happening.

I have tried putting in a usleep(200000);, and also tried [self.view setNeedsDisplay]; - - both to no avail.

Is there any way I can force the screen update BEFORE the blocking synchronous call? I know I can go to an async call, but I really don't want to do that since I cannot do anything in the app until/unless I get the data i need...

Thanks,
Jerry

here is the code I use to send the sync request: This is the relevant portion of the routine 'SendGetEventsRequest'.

```
NSURLResponse *response = nil;
NSError *error = nil;
[self.aiActivityIndicator startAnimating];
NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
```

Here are the other routines i use right before the above routine gets called:

```
- (IBAction)btnGetEvents:(id)sender {
// The user presssed the GetEvents button. Send the requested server to be processed.
[self.aiActivityIndicator startAnimating];
[self.lblCollectingEventNames setHidden:NO];
[self.lblEnterServerName setHidden:YES];
[self.btnGetEvents setHidden:YES];
[self.tfServerName setHidden:YES];
[self.view setNeedsDisplay];

[self SendGetEventsRequest:self.tfServerName.text];
}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField{
[self.tfServerName resignFirstResponder];
[self btnGetEvents:self];
return YES;
}
```

Basically, when the user presses the 'go' button on the keyboard, the routine textFieldShouldReturn gets called. I dismiss the keyboard then simulate pushing the button 'Get Events'.

In btnGetEvents, I start up the activity indicator, hide/show a few fields, then call sendGetEventsRequest. In there is the code where i do the Sync call.

I am setting up the activity indicator and show/hide fields BEFORE the sync call, yet they are not updated until AFTER the sync call returns.  I believe this is because the view controller did not perform a screen redraw before the Sync call got executed.

So, I need to figure out how to get the screen to update BEFORE the Sync call. I hope the additional code and additional explanation helps.

Comment: Can you please post up the code you are using to make the call and hide the fields, thanks

Comment: Check if http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15358602/self-view-setneedsdisplay-and-self-view-setneedslayout-are-not-working helps you.

Comment: Post the code where you make the sync call. I think you might be making the call in a non UI thread.

Comment: I updated the original question to show the code you requested.

Comment: In order to accurately answer your coding issue, you will need to show the relevant code you are having issues with. There could be many reasons why your code is not doing what you want it to do, but you need to show all your code. Where are you hiding the fields for example? Are you using delegate methods etc. The more information the better in order to get correct answer, as opposed to a guessed one. - The code you've posted isn't enough as it's missing where and when you're hiding the objects you talk about

Comment: Hi Jim, I added the code that was requested by iosDev82 - which asked specifically for the sync call. I understand why you may want to see the other code, but I was doing as I was asked.  Subsequent code has been published as per your request.

Answer (score 0):

Wow, I cannot believe I am the only person to have this issue. I modified my code to use the async call and it is working perfectly.